# Android Google Analytics Getting Referrer

Tags: android, google-analytics

When dealing with Campaign Measuring (see here) from Google Analytics SDK on Android, what is the best way to get the referrer?

I can successfully broadcast an intent to my app and i see in my logs that the campaign was found. What i need to do is take that referrer information and send it to my server for logging etc. When i broadcast manually where can i parse this referrer and consume it? When my app goes live, where should my code be so that on installation this referrer is sent to my server?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can implement your own receiver that gets the `referral` string extra from the `INSTALL_REFERRER` intent, does some work, and then passes the intent on to the Google Analytics receiver.

Here's an example:

```
package com.example.app;

import com.google.analytics.tracking.android.CampaignTrackingReceiver;

import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;


public class NotePadReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

  // The name of the referrer string broadcast by Google Play Store.
  private static final String PLAY_STORE_REFERRER_KEY = "referrer";

  @Override
  public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    String referrer = intent.getStringExtra(PLAY_STORE_REFERRER_KEY);

    // Do something with the referrer.

    // When you're done, pass the intent to the Google Analytics Campaign Tracking Receiver.
    new CampaignTrackingReceiver().onReceive(context, intent);

  }
}
```

Comment: Ok cool so i added a new file in my package and i'm trying to log the referrer `Log.e("---------REFERRER----------", referrer);` but nothing shows up in the log. Where in my project should this be exactly?

Comment: Is this something i would be able to test locally or will it only work with a published app?

Comment: Here is a piece of my trace that seems relevant: [trace](https://gist.github.com/hanleyhansen/5042b0506de4ee0a7e58)

Comment: You should be able to test this locally by broadcasting an INSTALL_REFERRER intent to your application, like the Google Play Store app does. Here's how you can do that:  [Broadcasting an INSTALL_REFERRER intent](https://developers.google.com/analytics/solutions/testing-play-campaigns#broadcast)

Comment: That's what I thought. That's also how i trade doing it yet my log is not getting captured. Here's a gist of [my entire file](https://gist.github.com/hanleyhansen/6b8bbf61e19dbc9f3814). Am i missing something to make sure my receiver intercepts that broadcast and then passes it on? I feel like it's getting skipped.

Comment: if I've implemented my own receiver, in AndroidManifest.xml, when I register the receiver, should I put my own receiver or GA Receiver?
<receiver android:name="com.google.analytics.tracking.android.CampaignTrackingReceiver">

or 

<receiver android:name="com.mycompany.helloworld.CustomReceiver">